# text font size in org-mode html export

Tags: html, emacs, org-mode

I'm beginner in org-mode and not a software engineer. I came across two html themes [here](https://github.com/fniessen/org-html-themes). However, I find that the font of text portion very small. I want increase the font size of the text portion under the headings. How do I achieve this? Where and what should I modify?

Comment: Did you look at the CSS for the theme you are interested in? E.g. for the ReadTheOrgs theme the [CSS](https://github.com/fniessen/org-html-themes/blob/master/styles/readtheorg/css/readtheorg.css) specifies relative font sizes for each element which you can play around with. The most important recommendation is: change *ONE* thing, examine the result and decide whether to keep or revert that change. Then make another change, examine the result etc. And don't be afraid of throwing it all away and starting from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to increase the text size in the generated html and don't want to get too involved in css you can just put this:-

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style>*{font-size: x-large;}</style>
```

at the top of your org file. see this; https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp for other values!

This should work with or without pulling in a CSS file...